# Problem installing xcode 4.6.2 on OS X 10.8.5

Tags: xcode, install

I need to install Xcode 4.6.2 on Mountain Lion 10.8.5. I got the dimg file from developer.apple.com, and ran it to install. This appeared to work, but when I click the icon in Finder, I get a dialog to install "Device Support." When I click Install, I get a message "An unknown error occurred. See the install log for more details." There is no way to make progress and no relevant message in the log. Please note, I have admin privileges while I do all this.

I have searched this site for similar questions, but all I found was a very similar (identical) problem with Xcode 4.6.2 and Lion 10.7.5 - but there was no answer. (I know that this version of Xcode does work with OS X 10.8.2, so I don't think compatibility is a problem here.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  I was installing 4.60 on OSX 10.9.5 using Parallels. I followed the answer to the question found here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3863980?start=0&tstart=0

That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Change date to something in 2014 and it should go fine, an issue with expired cert